# How to change the value of button

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

I am using spring mcv with ibatis and jsp for viewing.
my question is in jsp page, i am viewing like a data table containing a BUTTON at last column which is rendering from spring  controller  as my jsp page shown below.

```
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${hotellistdisplay}">

<td width="auto" align="center" class="row2"><b>
  <input type="button"  name="mybutton" id="${aff.hotel_id}" class="view" value="Deactivate">
  </b> </td>
```

there is 10 row containing button but as user click on a one of row the value of button should changed to ACTIVE without affecting the other row button. 
Though i got the code on based of class i am changing the value but it reflects all other button too.
I want the value  shouls be changed for particular for which the user click..

any help plz.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use class attribute, but use `this` instead inside your function:

```
$(".view").click(function(){
   $(this).val("ACTIVE");
});​
```

Demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jB7EP/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `val()` method, try the following:

```
$('td input[type="button"]').click(function(){
   $(this).val('active')
})
```

or:

```
$('tr td').click(function(){
   $('input[type="button"]', this).val('active')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').click(function(){
   $(this).find('input[type="button"]').val('ACTIVE');
})
```